# Web-tab blank display

Tags: tab

I tried to create a test single column full page web-tab but all it shows is a blank page. I went to create>tabs>web tabs. Am I missing something? Following is the link I tested for the web-tab...

[Mozilla: About Us](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=IFRAME-or-Web-Tab-Content-Displays-Blank-Page-1327107637323&language=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Mozilla server has set a header to indicate that it does not allow the content to be embedded in an iframe - this is typically used to avoid clickjack attacks. If you use something like the Chrome Inspector, you will see the error:

[image]

There's more detail on the X-Frame-Options header at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thanks @bob-buzzard. Is there any work around for such contents to be displayed on visualforce?

Comment: I'm afraid not - the browser will respect the wishes of the server and refuse to display the content.  The best I've been able to do is open a popup window through javascript to display the content.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong about your tab, here if you check error in browser it is like:

> Refused to display 'https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
>   You can find what exactly this error says [@here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012933/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sa)

You can try with replace url :  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008jqBIAQ
It is working!